# Make a copy of a List with abstract type to a List with specific type

Tags: java

first of all my code below just delivers an abstract view of my classes so that you can easily understand what my question is about :) -so also no equals, hashcode.

I have an ABC extended from **Observable** which has a List of **AbstractObservers**

Then I have some classes **B and C** inherit from AbstractObservers. AbstractObservers implements Observer.

The focus is now at the Recover class.

With the method recover() I try to return a List with the concrete type (B or C) instead of AbstractObservers.

I am not satisfies with my solution, I think it could be better, easier?

Have you any idea how I could solve that problem better? The Abstract classes must stay due to Hibernate.

Thank you in advance

```
public abstract class ABCObservable extends Observable {

    List<AbstractObserver> abstractObserverList = new LinkedList<>();

    public List<AbstractObserver> getAbstractObserverList() {
        return abstractObserverList;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void addObserver(Observer o) {
        super.addObserver(o);
        abstractObserverList.add((AbstractObserver) o);
    }
}
```

**AbstractObserver**

```
public abstract class AbstractObserver implements Observer {
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {

    }
}
```

**B**

```
public class B extends AbstractObserver {
}
```

**C**

```
public class C extends AbstractObserver {
    }
```

**Recover**

```
public class Recover {


    public List<? extends AbstractObserver> recover(ABCObservable abcObservable) {
        List<AbstractObserver> returnList = new LinkedList<>(); //does that delivers a List with AbstractObserver or B or C?
        if (abcObservable.getAbstractObserverList().get(0) instanceof B) {
            returnList = new LinkedList<>();
            returnList.addAll(abcObservable.getAbstractObserverList());
        } else if (abcObservable.getAbstractObserverList().get(0) instanceof C) {
            returnList = new LinkedList<>();
            returnList.addAll(abcObservable.getAbstractObserverList());
        }
        return returnList; // returns a List with B or C elements
    }
}
```

Comment: What is using `recover()`?  It seems that caller of `recover()` would have the context and be able to cast to the concrete List type.  But what is done with the recovered List which needs it to be a concrete type?

Comment: No the caller of recover() decides due to the type in the List what is to do next. But recover() must already deliver the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can't convert a list to a new type, what you can do, however, is create a new one and add the values to it. If you use a generic method, you should be able to accomplish this. I haven't test this code, but theoretically it should work:

```
public <T> List<T> recover(T abcObservable) {
    List<AbstractObserver> list = abcObservable.getAbstractObserverList();
    List<T> returnList = new LinkedList<>();
    returnList = new LinkedList<>();

    for(AbstractObserver a : list) {
        if(a instanceof T) {
            returnList.add(a);
        }
    }

    return returnList;
}
```

Instead of using a defined class, this snippet uses `T`, you can find out more about how Java Generic Methods work on [this Java Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).

EDIT: I think I'm confused about what you are asking for, this doesn't answer your question, if I understand it correctly.